# Como atualizar o APK da minha aplicação, quando o usuário solicitar?

Tags: android, versionamento, atualização

## Explicação:

Tenho uma aplicação que constantemente é feito bastante alterações, e toda vez que eu faço, eu gero uma versão nova com a mesma Private Key(*Keystore*), ou seja, quando eu mando a nova ***.APK** instalar no dispositivo nenhuma configuração é perdida e a aplicação é simplesmente atualizada. Até aí tudo bem.

## Pergunta:

Porém, eu não quero que o usuário tenha que baixar uma nova ****.APK*** no meu site e posteriormente instalar toda vez que for necessário atualizar ela, eu gostaria de fazer um botão "Atualizar" e quando clicar, transferir a nova ***.APK** com uma barra de progresso monitorando o fim do download para o aparelho, e automaticamente instalar ela, com outra barra de progresso monitorando o fim da instalação(*se não for possível pode ser um "ajax" que seria aquele progresso que fica girando sem previsão*), como devo fazer isto?

## Detalhe importante:

Não quero utilizar o Google Play para fazer isto para mim pois alguns usuários que possuem minha aplicação não podem, em determinado momento, utilizar, por exemplo, a versão 1.21, e somente a 1.20, já outros usuários já podem atualizar para a versão 1.21.

E também, não gostaria que a atualização fosse realizada automaticamente, pois preciso que o usuário acabe todos os serviços em sua aplicação antes de poder atualizar. E ele só deve atualizar quando for solicitado para que clique no botão.

Comment: Porque não simplesmente coloca seu app na play store e deixe o google fazer isso por você?

Comment: Porque não é todos os usuários que podem atualizar meu aplicativo em determinados momentos, alguns usuários só podem utilizar a versão 1.20 por exemplo e outros já podem utilizar a 1.21.

Comment: Você consegue disponibilizar versões diferentes para cada grupo de usuários pela play store.

Comment: Mas mesmo assim, não posso deixar que atualizem quando quiserem, minha aplicação que deve controlar se ela pode ser atualizada, ou seja, ela só deve ser atualizada quando não houver nenhum serviço em aberto no aplicativo, só quando o usuário terminar todos os serviços que ele pode atualizar. Ele deve estar ciente desta atualização e a versão que ele deve baixar deve ser compatível(eu checo isto)

Comment: eu li sua pergunta e fiquei pensando, porque você não pede para encerrar todos os serviços que a aplicação estiver executando quando o usuario clicar em "atualizar". (avisando o usuario que o app encerrará todas as atividades)

Answer (score 2):

Você até pode ter um botão no aplicativo que baixa uma apk, mas o usuário terá que acessar essa apk e requisitar a atualização manualmente. Apenas o sistema operacional pode fazer a atualização de um aplicativo. Nenhum app tem esse nível de permissão, pois seria uma grave falha de segurança, principalmente se sua APK requer novas permissões.

A Play Store oferece todos os recursos necessários para disponibilizar novas versões para os usuários, sendo inteligente o suficiente para não entrar em conflito com nenhum serviço em execução.

Se você acha que sua aplicação vai se comportar de maneira inesperada durante uma atualização, você precisa reproduzir esse erro e postar o código e a exceção aqui.

Recomendo não tentar reinventar a roda e utilizar a Play Store.

Comment: Mas por exemplo: na minha aplicação o usuário tem pedidos em aberto, que estão no banco, então ele não poderia atualizar até enviar estes pedidos para o servidor, porque vai que eu mudei tudo a parte do pedido na atualização, dai os pedidos dele vão estar todos errados, entende?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Se você está falando de SQLite, consegue tratar isso facilmente no método `onUpgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode baixar o apk e mandar instalar normalmente:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INSTALL);
```

Ou você pode criar um app que carrega consigo um novo .apk e instala com o mesmo código acima, só deve ser testado no caso de atualização (pois instalação funciona).

Comment: baixar e mandar instalar sozinho com toda aquela frescura do android que o usuário tem que interagir, eu já consegui, porém eu gostaria que por exemplo clica em atualizar enche uma barra de progresso e pronto tá atualizado, dai renicia app e cabou. eu quero pular aquela parte de abrir com pacote de instalador pra aceitar instalar ver o que ele vai usar aquele esquema de proximo instalar etc.

Comment: ? link errado? não achei nada relacionado em nenhum comentário nessa página.

Comment: A ideia é que seu APK tenha as funções de verificar atualizações, atualizar, e chamar uma activity principal de um Jar externo (DEX). O processo de atualização envolveria você trocar apenas os Jar (não envolve interação com o usuário).

Talvez você precise disso: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

Comment: Desculpe, mas não consegui entender muito bem... se você editasse sua resposta esclarecendo isto que me passaste seria ótimo :)

Comment: Funções do seu APK: 
1. Verificar atualizações; 2.Atualizar; 3.Chamar sua Activity principal; 
Todo o código de seu app ficaria em arquivos .jar (inclusive sua Activity Principal) e não no .apk. Ao instalar pela primeira vez seu app, você carrega junto esses .jar externos (que são em tese seu app). O processo de atualização modificaria esses .jar. Ficou mais claro?

Comment: mais ou menos, porque pra mim é a apk que é a aplicação mas se ela virar jar o que vai mudar? tipo não sei como transformar minha aplicação em um jar, ficaria igual pra compilar e desenvolver?

Comment: Você cria um projeto android e outro projeto Java comum (com import para a lib do android). O projeto java gera um jar. Esse jar você vai importar no seu projeto Android. Coloquei o link de 'custom class loading' porque talvez você precisará disso. Infelizmente, eu vi isso funcionando em um projeto em que não trabalho mais e não tive muito contato, por isso não posso passar informações mais detalhadas tecnicamente.